# How to parse "data-text" with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

There is a part of the HTML code:

```
<div class="some div name" data-text="important text">...</div>
```

We need to get the text from "data-text". I was trying to find something in the BeautifulSoup official documentation, but there is nothing like this (or I was looking badly).

Comment: 1. Pass your html object into beautiful soup.
Ldata = BeautifulSoup("<div class="some div name" data-text="important text">...</div>");
2. Get the attributes you are looking for from the div.
ldataText = Ldata.attrs['data-text'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have just to replace 'href' with 'data-text' in this code:

```
html = urlopen("http://kite.com")
text = html.read()
plaintext = text.decode('utf8')
links = re.findall("href=[\"\'](.*?)[\"\']", plaintext)
print(links[:5])
```

https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-get-href-links-from-urllib-urlopen-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You can use `['data-text']` or `.get('data-text')` on tag to get attribute value.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="some div name" data-text="important text">...</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('div', {'data-text': True})['data-text'])
```

Prints:

```
important text
```

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly the way I want it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
...
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, features = "html.parser")
div_tag = bsObj.find("div", class_ = "some div name")
if div_tag:
    data_text = div_tag['data-text']
print(data_text)
```

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

With so little information you provide, I can not come up with anything better than this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="some div name" data-text="important text">...</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.select_one('div.some.div.name')
print(div.get('data-text'))
```

Output:

```
important text
```